# LaTeX Error: Command \example already defined

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I use the refman classes refart and refrep to write papers for my user group conference proceedings.

I also use the documentclass beamer to prepare my slides.

Recently I began single-sourcing my slides and handouts
by using three files

1. my-slides-main
2. my-slides-ppt
3. my-slides-handout

---

```
%% my-slides-handout.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}
this is doc-class article,
usepackage beamer.
%% input{my-slides-main}
\end{document}


%% my-slides-handout.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
this is doc-class beamer
%% input{my-slides-main}
\end{document}
```

I want to use documentclass refart with package beamerarticle
but get the following error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \example already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

---

```
%% my-test-refart-beamer-article
\documentclass{refart}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}
this is doc-class refman.article: refart,
usepackage beamerarticle.

the error in the log is

LaTeX Error: Command \example already defined.

\end{document}
```

I have kludged a work-around 
by opening up the refart.cls
and disabling the definition of

```
 \newenvironment{example}
```

yes, I am aware that this is -not-

```
  \newcommand\example
```

but that kludge works.

of course when I upgrade from TeXlive.2013 to TeXlive.2014
I 'lost' that fix.

so my question is:

Q: what is the politically correct way to resolve a duplication of
commands or environments by class and packages.

```
\documentclass{refart}
%% i.e. what goes here 
%% to tell the package not to allocate, again \example?
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
```

note: I have searched the beamer *.sty files looking for
\newcommand\example
and have found nothing.

Comment: It's not a good idea to change class files ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can load `beamerarticle` with the `notheorems` option, that disables the default definition of all the theorem-like environments.

```
\documentclass{refart}
\usepackage[notheorems]{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}

This runs without errors.

\end{document}
```

Of course, you'll have to define yourself the theorem-like environments you need.

---

Why the `refart` class calls `example` an environment that does `verse` in typewriter font is beyond my comprehension.

> Die `example`-Umgebung erzeugt eine `verse`-Umgebung, schaltet allerdings auf `tt` und versucht einen Seitenumbruch vor der Umgebung zu vermeiden.

Comment: "Why the `refart` class calls example an environment that does `verse` in typewriter font is beyond my comprehension." That's *absurd*...

Comment: thank you. That is the politically correct answer I was looking for.

Comment: thank you CH and egreg. That [notheorems] is the politically correct answer I was looking for. I have played with modifying the class files and saving with a new name and that is not something I want to commit to whenever I get a new TeXlive installation.  I am interested to know how you traced the loading of the definition to the theorems and amsthm package.

Answer (score 2):

This runs without error.

```
\documentclass{refart}
\let\example\relax
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}
this is doc-class refman.article: refart,
usepackage beamerarticle.

the error in the log is

LaTeX Error: Command \verb!\example! already defined.

\end{document}
```